# How to get a future date thanks to number of working days in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, timezone

I would like to calculate the ending date from the starting date.
I have the number of workings days (so without sunday and saturday).
This is my function :

```
def ending_date(start_date, number_of_working_days)
  date = 0
  ending_date = start_date
   while date > number_of_working_days
    next if ending_date.sunday? || ending_date.saturday?
     finish = ending_date + 1.day unless date.saturday? or date.sunday?
     date += 1
   end
   finish
end
```

And I get `nil`. I don't know why.
If somedoby can help me with this please :)

Comment: `date > number_of_working_days` => `0 > number_of_working_days`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With minimum changes it should looks like:

```
def ending_date(start_date, number_of_working_days)
  date = 0
  while date < number_of_working_days
    start_date += 1
    unless start_date.saturday? || start_date.sunday?
      finish = start_date
      date += 1
    end
  end
  finish
end

#> ending_date(Date.today, 5)
#=> #<Date: 2016-12-14 ((2457737j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```

But I prefer to write this method like something this:

```
def ending_date(date, number_of_working_days)
  result = []
  while result.size < number_of_working_days
    date += 1
    unless [6,0].include? date.wday
      result << date
    end
  end
  result 
end

# To take all the working dates
#> ending_date(Date.today, 5)
#=> [#<Date: 2016-12-08 ((2457731j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>, #<Date: 2016-12-09 ((2457732j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>, #<Date: 2016-12-12 ((2457735j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>, #<Date: 2016-12-13 ((2457736j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>, #<Date: 2016-12-14 ((2457737j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>]

# To take last working date
#> ending_date(Date.today, 5).last
#=> #<Date: 2016-12-14 ((2457737j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```

Comment: Indeed the `>` was in the wrong way ! This way should work. But my console turn for ever and nothing happen as if it were in an infinity loop.

Answer (score 2):

Enumerator seems to do the job, and it can give you much more information than just a date :

```
require 'date'

def future_working_days(start_date = Date.today)
  date = start_date
  Enumerator.new do |yielder|
    loop do
      date += 1 # NOTE: Should start_date be included?
      yielder << date unless date.saturday? || date.sunday?
    end
  end
end

def ending_date(number_of_working_days, start_date = Date.today)
  future_working_days(start_date).find.with_index(1) { |_, i| i == number_of_working_days }
end

# Show the next 10 working days :
puts future_working_days.take(10).map(&:to_s).join('->') # 2016-12-08->2016-12-09->2016-12-12->2016-12-13->2016-12-14->2016-12-15->2016-12-16->2016-12-19->2016-12-20->2016-12-21

# Date after 5 working days :
puts ending_date(5) #=> 2016-12-14

# How many working days until the next Friday the 13th of a leap year
puts future_working_days.find_index{|date| date.friday? && date.day == 13 && Date.leap?(date.year)} #=> 851
```

Notes :

- Parameters of `ending_date` have been switched to allow default date for start_date
- `future_working_days` is an infinite Enumerator. Don't try `future_working_days.to_a`! [Lazy](http://patshaughnessy.net/2013/4/3/ruby-2-0-works-hard-so-you-can-be-lazy) could be helpful.
- Should today be included in `future_working_days`?

Comment: According to my code, I just realize that I better do this method in javascript ! :( I'm going to publish your solution in a new question for translating it in js! Feel free to help. Thanks again

Comment: See my other answer. It should be pretty straightforward to implement it in javascript.

Answer (score 2):

It's also possible to calculate the `ending_date` directly, without any loop. Every 5 working days comes a week-end! I wrote the code for a Sunday as a start_date, and modified it with `start_date.wday` for the other days of the week. Saturday is a special case.

```
def ending_date(number_of_working_days, start_date = Date.today)
  if start_date.wday == 6 # Saturday is a special case
    start_date + number_of_working_days + (number_of_working_days-1)/5*2 + 1
  else
    start_date + number_of_working_days + (number_of_working_days-1+start_date.wday)/5*2
  end
end
```

I tested it for many `start_dates` and many `number_of_working_days`, and it seems to work fine.

I couldn't find a way to remove the if statement, though.

EDIT: If you work with `ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone` objects, just call `to_date` before calling `ending_date` :

```
time = Time.zone.local(2016, 10, 15, 15, 30, 45)
puts time.class                   #=> ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone
puts ending_date(5, time.to_date) #=> 2016-10-21
```

Comment: I prefer this solution, a bit easier to read ! However my start date format is `ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone` so it doesn't work, do you know what do I had to change ? I feel very confused with date format, it's not an easy thing